# Vector field of functions equalling real numbers

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

We consider the set $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}$ (i.e. all functions $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$). I've been asked to prove that this forms a real vector space (that is, a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$). The most straightforward way of doing this seemed to me to just show that it satisfies the axioms.

I've done this (it wasn't particularly difficult or tricky, so I'm assuming I've done it correctly...), but had a moment of confusion when I looked back at what I'd written.

So, for example, to show that it satisfies one of the distributive laws, I wrote the following:

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in V$. Then
$$\lambda(f+g)
= \lambda(f(n)+g(n))
= \lambda f(n) + \lambda g(n)
= \lambda f + \lambda g$$
as required.

First of all, is this correct? It seems so trivial really.

But mainly, when I write the first equals sign, the $f$ on the left is a member of $V$, but the $f(n)$ is $f$ evaluated at $n$, so is a member of $\mathbb{R}$. That's how I justify the next step, as we know about how addition and multiplication distribute in $\mathbb{R}$.

Am I really justified in using an equals sign there though? How can something in a vector space that is not a real number equal something that is a real number? That is, $f\not=f(n)$, surely?

Sorry if this question seems like it isn't a question at all; I'm not sure if I'm just reading too much into it and getting confused.

Comment: The (pedantically) correct chain of equalities would be $(\lambda(f+g))(n)=\lambda(n)((f+g)(n))=\lambda(f(n)+g(n))=\lambda f(n)+\lambda g(n)=(\lambda f)(n)+(\lambda g)(n)$. Since this is for all $n$ then $\lambda(f+g)=\lambda f+\lambda g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Yes, checking the axioms is not very enlightning and very trivial. But it is the only way to go.

Second: Equating $f$ with $f(n)$ is not justified, since, as you write $f$ is a function $\def\N{\mathbb N}\def\R{\mathbb R}\N\to \R$ and $f(n) \in \R$. But you can correct your line with small changes. First note, that you want to prove $\lambda(f+g) = \lambda f + \lambda g$ for $f,g \in \R^\N$. This is an equation for functions. Two functions $\N\to \R$ are equal if they are equal evaluated at every $n \in \N$, for $n \in \N$ we have 
$$ \bigl(\lambda(f+g)\bigr)(n)= \lambda(f+g)(n) = \lambda \bigl(f(n) + g(n)\bigr) = \lambda f(n) + \lambda g(n) = (\lambda f + \lambda g)(n) $$
As $n\in \N$ was arbitrary, this implies, $\lambda (f+g) = \lambda f+ \lambda g$.

Comment: thank you! I thought I was being rather sloppy with my reasoning, and the way you've written it makes much more sense.